# Установка подсветки синтаксиса php кода в emacs

Tags: php, emacs, debian, linux

На debian squeeze установил emacs. Создал файл с форматом *.php и открыл в emacs'е. Когда начал печатать код, то заметил что синтаксис не подсвечивается. Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071975/emacs-color-syntax-configuration) описано, что добавить в файл .emacs.